# Efficient incremental hash computation during program interpretation

Tags: hash, lisp, scheme, interpreter, memoization

I'd like to write a **recursively memoizing Scheme interpreter**. At any point during evaluation, the interpreter should be able to detect when it receives as arguments a pair of expression and environment that it has previously seen.

**Plain memoization of `eval` and `apply` is inefficient**. It would require looking up the arguments in a hash table on every call of `eval`/`apply`, which would require walking the entire (possibly big) arguments on hash table matches.

For example, assume that the interpreter evaluates the program

```
(car (list A))
```

where A evaluates to a big object. When the interpreter evaluates the application `(list A)`, it first evaluates `list` and `A` individually. Before it applies `list` to `A`, it looks up in its hash table whether it has seen this application before, walking the entire `A` object to compute a hash. Later on, when the memoizing interpreter applies `car` to the list containing A, it computes a hash for this list which again involves walking the entire A object.

Instead, I want to build an interpreter that **incrementally builds up approximately unique hashes**, avoiding recomputation where possible and providing a guarantee that collisions are unlikely.

For example, one could recursively extend each object that the interpreter operates on with the MD5 of its value, or, if it is a compound object, with the MD5 of its component hashes. An environment might store the hash for each of its variable/value entries, and the hash of the environment might be computed as a function of the individual hashes. Then, if an entry in the environment changes, it is not necessary to rewalk the entire environment to compute the new hash of the environment. Instead, only the hash of the changed variable/value pair needs to be recomputed and the global hash of the set of entry hashes needs to be updated.

**Does there exist related work on incrementally building up approximately unique hashes, in particular in the context of recursive memoization and/or program evaluation?**

Comment: But how would such an interpreter evaluate `(eq? (list) (list))` ?

Comment: If you take the meaning of `eq?` to be "Are two objects stored at the same memory address?", then it should return `true`.

Comment: Sorry... i meant `(eq? (list 'A) (list 'A))`. The form `(list ...)` is not a list object, but a list **builder**. A list object would be `'(A)`. I don't understand your example of call that could save time unless you are of course talking about higher level reasoning that know that the combination `(car (list <a> <b> <c>))` can be optimized to `<a>` without changing semantic if the other two expressions are side-effect free. A `list` call in general returns something different each time. If you want to introduce the idea of "pure" functions that can be memoized then `list` is not one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if expressions are immutable (no self-modifying code allowed) then you can use EQ equality on them. If environments are immutable, you can treat them likewise. EQ equality is fast since you're just taking the bits from the machine pointer to be a hash.

The problem then are assignments which mutate environments, causing expressions values to change. If they are allowed, how do deal with this.

One way would be to make a note of environments that contain destructive code in their lexical scopes and somehow annotate them so that the evaluator can recognize such "polluted environments" and not do the caching for them.

By the way, you obviously want hash tables with weak semantics for this so that any objects that become garbage do not pile up in memory.

Comment: Good points, thanks! To clarify my question: If an object is independently created in more than one place during evaluation, I'd like to catch this as well, which rules out EQ.

Comment: This may rule out EQ over the object, but it does not rule out a shallow member-for-member EQ that is applied during construction. I.e. there could be a map of objects under this shallow equality. For instance, for a cons, the shallow equality would mean that the CAR-s are EQ and the CDR-s are EQ. If the machine finds itself about to cons two values for which there already exists a cell, it can just return that cell. This is important because you don't want to be traversing large objects all the way down. (There is still an issue for large vectors.)

Comment: Neat. For reference, "hash consing" is a name for this technique. (I'll mark your answer correct once I have thought a bit more about applying this approach to the setting outlined in the question.)

Comment: The Red Dragon Book (*Compilers: Principles, Techniques and Tools*, Aho, Sethi, Ullman, 1988) also describes something like this in 5.2, in some paragraphs under the heading **Directed Acyclic Graphs for Expressions**.  The idea is the same: for a given operator and leaves, find a node with the same operator and leaves and reuse it.