# A Scheme interpreter that passes only relevant subsets of environments to eval

Tags: compiler-construction, functional-programming, lisp, scheme, interpreter

Is there an efficient way to build a Scheme interpreter that passes only the *relevant* subset of an environment to recursive `eval` calls?

For example, consider the following expression:

```
(let ([x 1]
      [y 2])
  (+ x 3))
```

When we evaluate `(eval '(+ x 3) env)`, the environment contains the bindings `{ x : 1, y : 2 }`. How would one write an efficient interpreter such that the environment only contains `{ x : 1 }`?

Of course, in general we cannot know beforehand whether a value is going to be used. What I am looking for is a coarse syntactic approach—maybe based on compiler optimization techniques?—that is more efficient than walking much of the environment at each recursive call to `eval` to filter out irrelevant values.

(Background: my [quest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308058/efficient-incremental-hash-computation-during-program-interpretation) to write a memoizing Scheme interpreter.)

Comment: I think it will strongly depend on how is you intermediate representation.

Comment: Assume that I'm starting from the SICP evaluator with lexical environments.

Comment: "efficient interpreter" is an oxymoron. If you want efficient, you go all the way and write a compiler. "How can I be the most efficient long distance runner I can be, subject to the constraint that I don't drop below 300 pounds?"

Comment: Despite the way I phrased the questions, I am not attached to writing an interpreter. Ideas on writing a compiler that generates memoized code are just as welcome.

Comment: @Kaz I don't think "efficient interpreter" is entirely oxymoronic. There's certainly educational value in exploring how to make an interpreter more efficient, even if it's just a step in the path to writing a compiler. See Lisp in Small Pieces chapter 6, which uses the goal of fast interpretation as a stepping stone to compilation.

Answer (score 3):

Sure: for every subexpression compute the [free variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables) of that subexpression and attach that to the AST somehow. Then on every recursive call to `eval`, restrict the environment to just the free variables of the expression you're about to evaluate.

Compilers usually do this at `lambda` boundaries to avoid creating closures that retain references to unnecessary values, because retaining those references might prevent objects from being GC'd. That is, for the following program

```
(let ([x 1]
      [y 2])
  (lambda (z)  ;; free vars = {x}
    (+ x z))
```

the closure for the `lambda` expression would contain the value of `x` but not `y`. But in general, doing that means that you can't use the dead-simple "list of frames" environment representation; you might have to flatten it (or at least copy and prune).

Some implementations also zero out local variables (variables not held by closures, the kind you would expect to see in registers or on the stack) when they're no longer used, particularly before non-tail calls.  That is,

```
(let ([x some-big-object])
  (f (g x) long-running-expression-not-involving-x))
```

might get translated to the low-level equivalent of

```
(let ([x some-big-object])
  (let ([tmp1 (g x)])
    (set! x #f)
    (let ([tmp2 long-running-expression-not-involving-x])
      (f tmp1 tmp2))))
```

The reason is the same: dropping references as early as possible means the objects can potentially be freed sooner. (It also means that they won't get held by captured continuations, similar to the closure case.) Google "safe for space" for more information.

Comment: One more idea: instead of actually filtering the environment (slow!), you could pass the free variables as a parameter to your memoization code so that it only considers the relevant parts when comparing (and hashing, if you're memoizing with hash tables). You still might want to filter things entered into the table, though, for space safety.

Comment: To make sure I understand the idea in your comment: When I get to a recursive call (syntax-node, env), I (1) get the list of free variables stored in syntax-node, (2) look up the value of each of these variables in the environment, and (3) build something like a sorted alist of these variables, which I use as the mem key. (In step (3), if I want to avoid walking this new object, even in the case of hash table matches, I could possibly build it using the "object DAG"/"value-number" idea described in the linked question.)

Answer (score 0):

The common compiler optimization of [dead code elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination) would do the trick here. Y is not used, so the Y binding can simply be removed.

To answer the general question of how to write an efficient interpreter I suggest creating an AST and then passing over it multiple time using various optimization techniques such as partial interpretation to pre-compute and simplify as much as possible.